# Unable to retrieve RSA Private key from Specification,

Tags: java

By using below program i generated public and private keys, convert them to specifications. Public key retrieved fine from the specification, but private key is not retrieved exactly from the specification. is anything wrong i did in the below program.

```
    import java.security.*;
    import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
    import java.security.spec.KeySpec;
    import java.security.spec.RSAPublicKeySpec;
    import java.security.spec.RSAPrivateKeySpec;

    public class KeyFactoryEx {
        public static void main(String args[]) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException,                 InvalidKeySpecException{
    KeyFactory factory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");

    KeyPair pair = keyGen.genKeyPair();

    PublicKey pubKey = pair.getPublic();
    PrivateKey priKey = pair.getPrivate();

    byte pubKeyEncoded[] = pubKey.getEncoded();
    byte priKeyEncoded[] = priKey.getEncoded();

    System.out.println("Public key is");
    for(byte b : pubKeyEncoded)
        System.out.print(b +" ");
    System.out.println();   

    System.out.println("Private key is");
    for(byte b : priKeyEncoded)
        System.out.print(b +" ");
    System.out.println();

    KeySpec pubKeySpec = factory.getKeySpec(pubKey, RSAPublicKeySpec.class);
    KeySpec priKeySpec = factory.getKeySpec(priKey, RSAPrivateKeySpec.class);

    System.out.println("Key Specifications are generated for public and private keys");

    System.out.println("Retrieving public key from pubKeySpec");
    PublicKey pubSpecKey = factory.generatePublic(pubKeySpec);
    pubKeyEncoded = pubSpecKey.getEncoded();
    for(byte b : pubKeyEncoded)
        System.out.print(b +" ");
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("Retrieving Private key from priKeySpec");
    PrivateKey priSpecKey = factory.generatePrivate(priKeySpec);
    priKeyEncoded = priSpecKey.getEncoded();
    for(byte b : priKeyEncoded)
        System.out.print(b +" ");
    System.out.println();
}
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It's actually the same key, it's just a different representation. If you try printing the class of the first PrivateKey, you'll notice it's RSAPrivateCrtKeyImpl. The second has type RSAPrivateKeyImpl.

You can cast the first PrivateKey to an RSAPrivateCrtKey and retrieve the CRT values along with the private exponent and modulus. The PrivateKey at the bottom however is not an RSAPrivateCrtKey but only an RSAPrivateKey, so it doesn't have CRT values.

You can rectify this by using RSAPrivateCrtKeySpec when you call getKeySpec rather than using RSAPrivateKeySpec.